# How much ice or snow will Sleet Storm and Ice Storm leave behind?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, duration

[Sleet Storm](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Sleet%20Storm) has a duration of **concentration up to one minute** and says:

> Until the spell ends, freezing rain and sleet fall in a 20-foot-tall cylinder with a 40-foot radius centered on a point you choose within range. The area is heavily obscured, and exposed flames in the area are doused. The ground in the area is covered with slick ice, making it difficult terrain.

It does not mention anything about the sleet vanishing when concentration ends.

[Ice Storm](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Ice%20Storm) is an **instantaneous** spell and says:

> A hail of rock-hard ice pounds to the ground in a 20-foot-radius, 40-foot-high Cylinder centered on a point within range. (...) Hailstones turn the storm's area of Effect into Difficult Terrain until the end of your next turn.

Here the difficult terrain effect only lasts until the end of the next turn. Does this mean the ice vanishes afterwards, or merely that the ice does not make the area difficult terrain any longer?

Are the effects of these spells natural substances that are then subject to normal physics, or are they magical ephemera, that vanish when the spells end?

Comment: I've closed this as a dupe, it seems this very same question has been asked about a different spell with the same problem - it doesn't tell us if the environmental hazards totally disappear.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov, thanks I had not found that reply, I searched for these two spells. For my purpose, I would like to know if the substance remains, not so much for the Difficult Terrain, but to use it as ice/snow for simulacrum. I have other ways to create ice, but these would have been a nice, quick way to do so.

Comment: For what it's worth, our GM rules that sure, no issue, it will leave behind a bunch of ice and sludge that can be used to make a simulacrum from. No need to freeze a lake with Freezing Sphere and hack it out of there, or getting someone to cast Ray of Frost ad nauseam (which would also need a GM ruling that you can target objects as with firebolt)